# Activity stack not getting cleared

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am facing a strange issue

1. Activity A gets called and Fragment A has been attached to it.
2. Method gets called (onCreate, onStart,onResume) .

: I received the notification and I tab on that with intent for Activity A.

> Blockquote
> (intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
> )

1. When Activity A is opened it call the below method.
2. (**onPause**,onCreate, onStart,onResume (Fragment detached) and than onDestroy)

   Why on destroy is called for the old instance of the activity when I have already called CLEAR_TOP.

Can someone help me what can be the cause for this?

How can I check if there is any instance is pending in stack already or how can I clear everything?
I can not use singleInstance as on notification tab I am redirecting to different fragment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use only `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` then all instances of activities will be cleared, back to **and including** the instance of the target `Activity`, and then a new instance of the target `Activity` will be created.

If you want to reuse an existing instance, you need to specify **both** `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` like this:

```
intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

This will clear all instances of activities back to (but **excluding** the target `Activity`, and call `onNewIntent()` on the target `Activity` with the new `Intent`.

Comment: I am wondering on click of Notification even though FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP clears all the instances, it is going though onPause() ,onCreate(),onStart(),onResume(),onDestroy and when it go through onPause() it detaches my current fragment and screen is blank.

Comment: There are 2 instances of the `Activity`. When the notification is clicked, `onPause()` of instance1 is called, then Android creates a new instance and `onCreate(), onStart() and onResume()` of the second instance are called. At some point later, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are called on the first instance.

Comment: Yes I agree , but can you please clear my doubt of why FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  is not able to clear the instance1 ?

Comment: It is. `onDestroy()` is being called on instance 1. Please add your manifest to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. Using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` will cause the current instance of the `Activity` to get destroyed. But this happens using the standard Android lifecycle. It doesn't just nuke the instance into oblivion like on Star Trek. It calls `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` so the instance can properly shut itself down. What is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, David, I was not clear on the first attempt although my problem is resolved. singleton instance of my fragment was creating the problem. I was creating the single object of the fragment and attaching the same to each instance of the activity that was the cause of misbehaving

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it. Can you write an answer and accept that answer please. Others may learn something from it. Or, if the question is no longer valid, then just delete the question.

Comment: the answer is the same as you suggested intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP. One should handle the lifecycle of an old instance in case If they have fragment attached to the activity because if you have implemented singleton pattern on the fragment object while attaching and detaching of the fragment to the activity it might be detached when old instance goes to on destroy.